# In a Views template, how can I mimic the effect of "Link this field to its taxonomy term page"?

Tags: views, theming

I have a view of taxonomy terms that displays **Fields**, including **Taxonomy term: name** and **Taxonomy term: Term ID**.

I am attempting to use a views template to customize the output of this view.

In the Views UI, if I click **Taxonomy term: name**, I can get an option to *Link this field to its taxonomy term page*.

I would like to use the link generated by this option in my views template output.

However, when I `dpm($row)`, only the term name and term ID are returned.  How does Views create the link to the taxonomy term, and how can I mimic this in my template file?

[image: taxonomy term dpm output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy-ish way to do that within the Views UI is with the option:

"Rewrite the output of this field"

1. Add term id field Check "Exclude from display"
2. Order the field so it's above the other fields
3. Edit the field you want to convert into a link
4. Check "Rewrite the output of this field"

e.g

```
<a href="/taxonomy/term/[tid]">[name]</a>
```

to create a link.

You can also add a global "Custom text" to add arbitrary text using the replacement tokens there as well.

In that way, tokens from your view fields can be made available as replacement pattern options in your View.

Comment: When I use *Link the field to its taxonomy term*, Views returns the link with the pathauto alias, not the taxonomy/term/[tid] link.  I was hoping to be able to grab that link instead, but if not your solution is a good compromise.

Comment: @PatrickKenny for the alias, you may be able to add the  excluded field "Path: The aliased path to this content." and use that in the replacement text href instead.